# How to physically shut off network interface in Linux (Redhat/Centos)

Tags: linux, redhat, linux-networking

Is there any way to shut off a network interface on a Linux box from the command line? By shut off, I mean to make the link power down as per a Cisco switch's "shutdown" command. `ip`, and `ifconfig` and even `rmmod <driver>` when used to bring a port down do not disconnect link; the device on the other end still sees a connection even when one disables a port using those utilities/methods.

Technically, at a device level I'm sure it can be done because when I perform

```
ip link set em1 down
ip link set em1 up
```

...then during the "up" phase, the NIC does go off for about 3-4 seconds (as seen on a switch's port cabled to that NIC, and on the port's status LED).

What I'm looking for is a command line utility that will perform the task. I have CentOS 7.2 on a Dell R610 using the onboard Broadcom nics.

As to why...

It's really easy and useful to double check a network connection when you can bounce an interface in the switch.

"But there's lldp". Except when there's not, such as with a Layer 1 switch. (Google "Metamako" for more information). Being able to toggle a server network interface could verify cabling from 2000 miles away.

"But you can already do that on the switch side." Yes, and isn't it glorious? Would that the functionality were available to Server administrators, on the server side.

"But if you can't connect to the host, well then it's already dead." Think about systems with 8 live network interfaces. You can easily log in to a system via the onboard interface and have many PCIe nic's down.

Comment: ...ethtool lies, btw. If it says "Link detected: no" it may be because the interface is disabled. However, the LED remains on and the switch still reports link. It seems that ethtool cannot tell the difference between a disabled interface and a cable that's been removed.

Comment: With explanation of why you'd want to do this, I still don't get it. Why?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin What? Just because you don't understand something it gets  a -1? Maybe you could be a little more constructive and offer a better alternative? Furthermore, when ethtool says "link detected: no" it's actually incorrect. It gives one the impression that the link is down, which would could be a red herring in any hardware troubleshooting. There should be a way to toggle the link status on a NIC. I can't believe no one has attempted to do this before.

Comment: What makes you think I down voted? I doubt anyone understands why you're asking this question. So why do you want to do this? Maybe you'll get some up votes if you clarify your question. Unclear/unuseful questions can get down voted. This might be helpful to you: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/842/why-downvote-a-question-or-answer-on-server-fault . Losing your temper doesn't get any points with me. I was hoping to be able to help you...

Comment: Points taken. I apologize. Clarified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately it doesn't exist a general way in linux.

In the networking world it is very common to toggle a port "Cisco: shut / no shut, Juniper disable/enable" to identify or trigger autonegotiation.

In Linux you have to rely on the individual driver for your network card.

Answer (score 5):

This works for my Intel I219-V (e1000e) card. No link light or anything, totally dead:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/remove
```

But when I do the same for a realtek (r8169) card, it still has a link light.

It may be something you cannot control on certain cards or perhaps there's something in the driver code that can be tweaked if you're into such things. That would be my next step if I were really determined.

Comment: Only seems to exist on very specific interfaces

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Worked great for my Lenovo x230's ethernet NIC which was wasting much power on doing nothing.